# Swift custom cell if else to change between label textbox

Tags: ios, swift, reuseidentifier

I have a table view that has a custom cell  class that has 2 labels & a textbox

the result set would display one of the labels for all rows (a name) then there is a if else statement to show either the second label or a textbox.

example 
label 1       label 2
joe blogs     Student
road runner   [TextBox]
etc...

however when rows gets scrolled off screen new rows label 2 doesnt get refreshed & has old data, however label 1 is perfect.

example 
label 1       label 2
joe blogs     Student
road runner   Student
etc...

below is the code snippet

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    //let size = CGSizeMake(30, 30)
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! SBGestureTableViewCell


    if strPaymentMethod[indexPath.row] == "Student" && dctMemAttEventDetails["StuDiscVenue"]! as! String == "Yes"
    {
        cell.txtMemberPaid.hidden = true
        cell.lblPaymentMethod!.text = strPaymentMethod[indexPath.row]

    }

    else
    {
       cell.lblPaymentMethod.hidden = true
       cell.txtMemberPaid.hidden = false
    }

    cell.lblMemberName!.text = strFirstname[indexPath.row] + " " + strSurname[indexPath.row] + " : " + strPaymentMethod[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

as requested 2 screenshots

the second screenshot shows the same info but as you can see for example the row (Know itall) should be cash & have the textbox however it has the label which says 'student' where on the first screenshot it is correct (you will see some others incorrect on the second screenshot if you look further down)

I know it has to do with the cells getting reused when they scroll off screen but the data not getting refreshed & its specifically the data  in the if/else statement thats not refreshing/redrawing properly.

I hope that clears your questions/comments with the screenshots of what i'm trying to achieve. if not please comment & ill try to a different approach to showing my problem.
if you have any further questions let me know ill answer them as soon as possible

thank you for any & all assistance.

[This is of the tableView when first loaded & no rows scrolled off screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jQRiY.png)
[This is of the tableView when scrolled down then back up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FxPha.png)

Comment: Shouldn't you set `cell.lblPaymentMethod.hidden = false` in your `if` clause?

Answer (score 0):

we would like to help, please explain more with either images and videos, and remove un-needed information, if the textbox isn't making a problem for you you can ignore it, and don't mention it, please be specific so we can help..
Good luck.

Edit : and yes, are you forgetting to reveal a hidden object ?

Comment: Zazu Just letting you know i added more info.. let me know if you require more

Comment: man, what is label1 and label2? you have lblPaymentMethod and txtMemberPaid, which of these don't refresh?